# Page speed insight shows FID & INP not applicable in desktop version of my website

Tags: pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals, interaction-to-next-paint

While checking my website https://www.mediyaar.com on page speed insights, the below web vitals showing **Not applicable** for my website

First Input Delay (FID)
Interaction to Next Paint (INP)

The values appears when i check it for mobile version .

How to fix this issue , Thanks in advance for you valuable input

Answer (score 0):

This is normal and there's no action needed on your part. It means that your website doesn't have enough user interaction data from real-world desktop users to report on the responsiveness metrics (FID, INP).